# Find the order of $8/9, 14/5,48/28$ in the additive group of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Find the order of $8/9, 14/5,48/28$ in the additive group of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

---

**JUNK**

Guessing asking for $8/9 * k = 0 $ (being a whole integer) for smallest integer so for this one is 9 . another guess would be the smallest element of $Q/Z$ being something like $9/8$

$14/5$ would be 5

$48/28=12/7$ would be 7?

---

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes, given that the OP has provided his own work. They don't really show intelligence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them are fine ($9$, $5$ and $7$). Notice, though, that $\dfrac {14} 5 = \dfrac 4 5$ in $\Bbb Q / \Bbb Z$ (which does not change your answer).

In general, the order of $\dfrac m n$ can be easily shown to be $\dfrac n {\gcd (m,n)}$:

- if $d = \gcd(m,n)$ then clearly

  $$\frac n d \frac m n = \frac m d \in \Bbb Z$$

  so the class of $\dfrac m d$ is $0 \in \Bbb Q / \Bbb Z$;
- if $1 \le k < \dfrac n d$ has the property that $k \dfrac m n = 0 \in \Bbb Q / \Bbb Z$, then $n \mid km$, i.e. $\dfrac n d \mid k \dfrac m d$; since $\gcd \left( \dfrac m d, \dfrac n d \right) = 1$, it follows that $\dfrac n d \mid k$, which is not possible since $k < \dfrac n d$.